# Getting error on declaring broadcast receiver in different thread

Tags: android, multithreading

i am trying to load a broadcast receiver in a different thread instead of my UI thread cause its slowing my app here is my broadcast receiver code :

```
private BroadcastReceiver battery_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isPresent = intent.getBooleanExtra("present", false);
        //String technology = intent.getStringExtra("technology");
        //int plugged = intent.getIntExtra("plugged", -1);
        //int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
        int health = intent.getIntExtra("health", 0);
        //int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", 0);
        //int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
        float voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
        if (voltage > 1000)
            voltage=voltage / 1000f;
        //int voltage = intent.getIntExtra("voltage", 0);
        float temperature = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", 0);
        if (temperature > 100) {
            temperature = temperature / 10f;
        }

        //int level = 0;
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.i("BatteryLevel", bundle.toString());
        if (isPresent) {

            //String info = "Battery Level: " + level + "%\n";
            //info += ("Technology: " + technology + "\n");
            //info += ("Plugged: " + getPlugTypeString(plugged) + "\n");
            //info += ("Health: " + getHealthString(health) + "\n");
            //info += ("Status: " + getStatusString(status) + "\n");
            //info += ("Voltage: " + voltage + "\n");
            //info += ("Temperature: " + temperature + "\n");
            setBatteryLevelText(String.valueOf(voltage) + " V");
            setBatteryLevelText2(String.valueOf(temperature) + " °C");
            setBatteryLevelText3(getHealthString(health));
        } else {
            setBatteryLevelText("Battery not present!!!");
        }
    }
};
```

and here is the code to load it on a thread

```
private void registerBatteryLevelReceiver() {
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Handler handler; // Handler for the separate Thread

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyNewThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
    handler = new Handler(looper);
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(battery_receiver, filter, null, handler);
//registerReceiver(battery_receiver, filter);
}
```

and all of them are before oncreate method but when i run it i get the error after few seconds after running the app with this error on logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: MyNewThread
                                                                 Process: com.soheil.prolightfa, PID: 8880
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 bqHint=4 (has extras) } in com.soheil.prolightfa.MainActivity$1@fce2659
                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1003)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                  Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8128)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1220)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:361)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.widget.TableLayout.requestLayout(TableLayout.java:227)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:20085)
                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:3316)
                                                                     at com.soheil.prolightfa.MainActivity.setBatteryLevelText(MainActivity.java:132)
                                                                     at com.soheil.prolightfa.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                     at com.soheil.prolightfa.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:101)
                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:993)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cause its slowing my app

That is very unlikely. Reading a few extras and updating a few `TextView` widgets will not take much time.

> but when i run it i get the error after few seconds after running the app with this error on logcat

The error message is fairly self-explanatory:

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

You cannot modify the UI from a background thread, as you are doing. Remove the `HandlerThread`.

Comment: @Soheyl: You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide your evidence of a performance issue and its location. IOW, explain *how* you have determined that you have a problem and that *this* code is the source of that problem. The only way that receiver should be a source of performance problems is if it is invoked too frequently. `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` shouldn't be invoked anywhere near that frequently, though there could be buggy devices and custom ROMs out there that broadcast that too much.